# SendGrid modifies links inside email and they dont redirect to correct page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendgrid

I have a rails app running in production with sengrid. 
At one point in my app I am sending an email with a confirmation link which redirects to a specific confirmation page :

```
%a.button.button-custom.button-blue{href: confirm_votes_path(@vote.confirmation_token, only_path: false)
```

However in production, Sengrid seems to modify the link inside my mails. I get something like :

```
href="https://u3881616.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=pVistOUxWTXmIPFqqAw0AnJt-2BbCLbreZ3xbCIcCjU0qXsxlkph8Wd3VafON-2FVyJfT0PWClbesX-2F2oOjnxeXwwaDA80aCKixoULvRGUX7PgDg59Vde4HU6spxlzuqyUUF_e4qGN2gUHpERWs59wU8LHyeuQCdWWdC4Yjpw10HvUcUonj0ZfIp-2FiYACT83qOqsHMBnkJGcBsjpIoSUjVySxVhEtqCz7myXFB-2B7uTWKruQbH-2BG7-2FI2-2BFdmXC6nbf-2FFpgyNUivvir0Upib8e5r8YJY3caF-2BpKD-2FscuINwBQkM7n008mEGADo5w5w5fejlzhopGHvJegbSRePJ-2BBu3b3olUhP2q-2BX4lyJAYvegG4xnDPU-3D"
```

and the link redirects to the base url of my website and not the good confirmation url like it does locally.

What is going on with SendGrid here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to disable [click tracking](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html).

Comment: Keep in mind sometimes it takes some to for this change to take effect. Not much, it took only 5 minutes for me, but enough to makes you think it's not working after you do a first test.

Answer (score 1):

What should the final URL look like? SendGrid is click-tracking, like bwest said, but that will still work with tokens in the URL and such. SendGrid does the substitution-variable replacement first, then tracks the resulting URL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be encountering an issue with link tracking in SendGrid, which modifies links in outgoing emails to redirect through a tracking domain before forwarding to the original destination. This can sometimes cause issues if the link is already a local URL on your own site.

One solution is to disable link tracking for specific URLs in your emails by adding a clicktracking=false parameter to the link URL. For example, if your link URL is https://example.com/my-page/, you could modify it to https://example.com/my-page/?clicktracking=false.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar issue, wherein the CNAME records for the branded link were absent from our domain provider's DNS settings.

To resolve this, we needed to insert a new CNAME record. We specified the HOST (url1234.ourdomain.com) and set the VALUE as 'sendgrid.net'